# How to filter queries in GQL with Entities created by objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have the following table called MACObs in the Datastore Viewer:

```
ID/Name         accessPoint             mac                     obs
id=42310053     xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx       yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy       302 bytes, SHA-1 = 031688dc48d2e71bc80b1c16016cbb108c5af3e7
```

So now I thought I can do a GQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MACObs WHERE accessPoint = 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'
```

But when I run this query, I get only this answer:

```
No results in Empty namespace.
```

Maybe its important to say that I create the entities in the backend with objectify.

Comment: It should have worked. One question : is accessPoint a TEXT type or String type ? TEXT types are not indexed by default.

Comment: It's a string. And in objectify also.

Comment: And you are trying this query in the datastore viewer and it is returning No results. Other than a mismatch in the values, I am not too sure why?

Comment: Yes I'm trying this in the datastore viewer because I want to find my failure in my objectify expression looking like this: ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(MACObs.class).filter("accessPoint", macOfAP) where macOfAP is a String which I can find in the datastore viewer.

Comment: Can you show me your entity definition via Objectify annotations?

Comment: [at]Entity
public class MACObs {
    [at]Id
    private Long id;
    private String mac;
    private String accessPoint;

    [at]Serialize
    private ArrayList<Long[]> obs;

and then the setter and getter

sry I don't know how to write an at as symbol without meaning an user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Here is the documentation from Objectify "Objectify does not index properties by default. You must explicitly define single-property indexes with the @Index annotation."

So try out the following: Add an @Index annotation to your accessPoint attribute.

So your definition will become:

```
@Entity 
public class MACObs { 
  @Id private Long id; 
  private String mac; 
  @Index private String accessPoint; 
  @Serialize private ArrayList<Long[]> obs; 
  ...
  getter/setter methods
  ...
}
```

Comment: Did it address the problem ?

Comment: Yes. I worked only with postgres and hibernate before and something like this is new to me.